# Get route that caused user redirection to login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application that the user needs to be logged in, in order to access some pages in the website.

I need to show the user a custom message on the log-in page based on the pages user tried to access. How can I identify which route caused the redirection to the log-in page in laravel ?

Comment: You can store the URL as a session variable before you redirect the user. Then, when the user have been redirected, you can simply read that session variable to get the URL the user got redirected from.

Comment: The user is redirect by the middleware Auth (by default).